# Does these dots mean anything?

Tags: voltage, transformer, symbol, schematic

I'm new to electronics, so my knowledge on symbols is not quite complete yet. So I have an old transformer schematic and I have to get the voltages as accurate as possible. Some voltages are very straightforward, but some contain dots (more on the pictures). Can anybody give me an idea what their meaning is?

[image: Transformer]
[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are decimal points, used in the usual way, for example 6.3. The placement makes them easier to read.

As usual, the voltages will be AC RMS.

Comment: I didn't see decimal points used like this before, but now at least I'm familiar with this placement. Thank You! It helped a lot!

Comment: It used to be the standard decimal point in the UK.  But then computers and typewriters took over, and everybody started using fulls stops instead.